# What locations can a given player access?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

If you have, let's say, a 4 by 4 graph and arrange the pieces in the following.

[image: Example table]

What I want to accomplish is when I click one of the pieces, I want to see all of the moves available for that given piece that doesn't require moving through another one. For example,

[image: Potential moves]

What's the best way to accomplish this programmatically? I'm doing this in Unity but I'm mostly curious to see an algorithm to do this.

Comment: Sounds like a maze routing problem, check lee algorithm as an example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm. You just dont have the target location - repeat loop until you dont have place to move (no points to be marked) .

Comment: It seems like you want a DFS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The DFS is a simple algorithm that can achieve what you want.

It works like that:

```
DFS(x, y):
    mark[x, y] = true
    for i = -1 ... 1:
        for j = -1 ... 1:
            if (x + i) < 0 || (x + i) >= columns  //outside of matrix
                continue
            if (y + j) < 0 || (y + j) >= rows     //outside of matrix
                continue 
            if mark[x + i, y + j]                 //already seen
                continue
            if matrix[y + j, x + i] is empty
                print("You can go to position (" + (y + j) + ", " + (x + i) ")");
                DFS(x + i, y + j)
```

It will look all available slots and give them to you.

You can start it by calling `DFS(column, row)` with your initial position.